# How to open a vf page as a modal from another vf page on button click

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

I have this below code where on button click I open a modal. If I separate the modal content into a different `Visualforce Page`, how can I display it as modal popup?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Test</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can replace <p>Some text in the modal.</p> with the iframe.

Comment: most likely you would put `<apex:include>` within the modal and use JS to shoe and hide the modal

Comment: Why would you want to use another VF page as the modal content? I could see a Component perhaps, but a page doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Check this SFSE link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46230/how-to-load-seperate-vf-page-as-modal-dialog-without-risky-iframes